# Need help converting VB.NET 08 code to PHP - Getting direct link from MediaFire.com

Tags: php, vb.net

I was looking for a way to get a direct link from mediafire's file hosting service. By default, when a user visits a download link, he will be presented with a download page where he has to wait for the download to be processed and then a link will appear.
This link will appear in the div id 'download_link'.

I googled and found a VB.NET 2008 solution to this, but I need the code in PHP
Here is the VB.NET 2008 solution: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=556681

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This VB.NET code relies on access to the client DOM through the WebBrowser .NET control. You could port this to PHP by:

- Using the cURL functions to get the HTML
- Loading them into an HTML parser to find the correct link
- Redirecting the user with `Header('Location: '.download_link)`

I think it would be better to recommend to your users the [SkipScreen](http://skipscreen.com/) Firefox extension, though. A client solution will always be easier.